# How do I add 2 date/times together?

Tags: javascript

I have to add the current time with another one.

For example, the time now is `10:30 on 21st July 2011`.

I want to book a vehicle for today at `17:00`, but `10:30 + $minHours < 17:00` which means that I cannot make the booking.

Here is my code:

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_day = d.getDay();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var hours = d.getHours();
var minutes = d.getMinutes();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();

a = d_names[curr_day] + ', ' 
    + curr_date + ' ' 
    + m_names[curr_month] + ' ' 
    + curr_year;

t1 = document.getElementById('min_hr');

if(a == e.value) 
{
    alert("please call reservation to make a booking for collection in the next 24 hours");
    return false;
} 
else 
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: where you want to add the 2nd time and sould the 2nd one be the same time?

Comment: Strictly speaking it does not make sense to add two times.  What is 9:32am + 4:15pm?  It does, however, make sense to add a time and a _duration_.  What is 10:15am + 3.5 hours?  Answer: 1:45pm.  (Sorry fo r the lame U.S. twelve-hour timestamps.)  What exactly are you trying to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
d.setMinutes ( d.getMinutes() + 30 );
```

Check the properties of `Date` instance here [Date - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), especially the getters and setters there.

If you want to set the hours use

```
//An integer between 0 and 23, representing the hour
d.setHours ( d.getHours() + 2 );
```

The signature of the method is

```
setHours(hoursValue[, minutesValue[, secondsValue[, msValue]]])
```

Code for your exact requirement is this.

```
var $maxHour = 17; //5 PM
var $minHours = 3;
var $hourNow = new Date().getHours();
if( ( $minHours + $hourNow ) > $maxHour ){
    alert("Time is up.");
}
else{
    alert("Please book now");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just make a new object.
Above you refer to  `var d = new Date();` writing `d.getDay();`.

Now you make a new object: `var d2 = new Date(/* something in here */);` and refer to it by `d2.getDay();`

Is that an answer to your question?

edited. Now you can add any hours to your date:

```
var d = new Date();
var d2 = new Date();
d2.setHours(d.getHours() + 2);
```

Comment: I have to add current time with another time

Answer (score 0):

- have one date object .
- Convert the time you want to add to it into
  number of minutes ( or seconds ) .
- Set the minutes(seconds) of the date object as it's original value + the value computed in Step 2.