# create 'time finishing' from value

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, time

I have a countdown timer in jQuery with a pause/resume function.

I'd like to take the "totalSeconds" value and add it to the current time so that I can display what time the countdown will finish...

so it'd be "current time" + "totalSeconds" on the page load(?)

How would you calculate this and create the `<p>` tag with jQuery?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813423/adding-time-using-javascript

Comment: `var date = new Date(); date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + totalSeconds);`. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code would append the `<p>` element to the end of the body tag.
If you want to format the date, you could use [this](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-dateFormat) jquery plugin, or some simple string manipulation.

`var totalSeconds = 300;

var date = new Date();

date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + totalSeconds);

$("body").append("<p>"+date+"</p>");`